# Adding multiple box-shadows in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, filter

My question is rather simple, I'm attempting to draw a `map` with several colored cells in it. Since I don't want to clutter my page with hundreds of `div` cell, I want to make a single `div` and then paint on it "manually" by using several `box-shadows`.

However, I need to modify them dynamically, and so I try using 
`$("#mapid").css("box-shadow", "my_shadow_data");`
 And it turns out that `JQuery` only takes a single argument; I can't make several `box-shadows` by separating them with a comma.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Create your css styles then get jQuery to apply them to the relevant object/element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always pass an object inside your css (...). Take a look at my example. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#mapid").css({
  "color":"white",
  "backgroundColor": "red"
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "mapid">hello</div>
```